# Issue with Creating Azure Marketplace Offering for Multi-Container Application

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-aks, azure-marketplace, azure-managed-app

I am currently working on creating an offering on the Azure Marketplace for my application, which is of the multi-container type. I am considering the option of using a "managed application" offering to allow both customer and publisher control over the services.

The main issue I am facing is the character limit in the docker-compose file (4000 characters) when using Azure App Service as the service. However, it is crucial for my application.

I explored the option of using Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) to overcome the limitation, but I realized that, in this case, the user would only deploy the service infrastructure without the application ready.

I am seeking suggestions on how to handle this situation. I thought of using a deployment script to perform the application deployment at a later stage after the offering is deployed.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation, or does anyone have ideas on how to best handle this issue? Are there alternatives I may not have considered?

Thank you in advance for the assistance!

Comment: App Service might not be the right service with such a large compose file. Note that some compose features are not available on App Service and are ignored so you may be able to trim the file down.

Comment: Reducing the character count of the Docker Compose file may not be a viable solution in my case, considering that the application employs numerous microservices. In this context, what could be the most suitable service for deployment?

Comment: Are you using any of these? build, depends_on, networks, secrets.

Comment: Currently, I am working on a content application with the goal of releasing an offer on the Azure marketplace.

After careful consideration of the available options, I am leaning towards the use of a "managed application". This choice stems from the need to ensure that the resources used are easily editable and editable by me as an editor. I believe that this approach will allow greater flexibility in the management of resources.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.